# C++ Opencl wrapper reference counted?

Tags: c++, opencl

Are the classes in the C++ OpenCL wrapper reference counted? Does the "Copy Constructor" for contexts and buffers make a copy to the references of the class, that is cleaned up only when all references are cleared (like a shared ptr?) The documentation is kinda vague...

Comment: I would hope so, otherwise it would be a rather useless wrapper. You can always look at the code to check, though I will agree it is a pain (my eyes are still bleeding from having to sift through hundreds of lines of weird macro/template voodoo in the AMD wrapper implementation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is - look at line 1090 of [cl.hpp](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.1/cl.hpp), specifically Wrapper (and ReferenceHandler).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Make sure to check for bugs in cl.hpp. At least one version has bugs releasing references. https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/520409